# How to check data for duplication in database?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I have 3 fields of topic name in 3 different languages. When entering new topic I'm using JavaScript to show on the page if that topic exists already in the database by using `select` and `like clause` statement. The problem is it finds any duplication if the topic name entered exactly the same, but not if only some words are the same.

How do I check for duplication on topic that checks the words for similarity and not the whole topic?

Comment: Split the string into words (separating at spaces) and check for 'WHERE x LIKE '%this%' OR x LIKE '%is%' OR x LIKE '%an%' OR x LIKE '%example%''? Of course, you'd need to use a dictionary, to erase all 'common words, like 'this', 'is', or 'a'...stuff that's bound to be in a LOAD of topics.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code and some of the data please? I assume that you are using wildcards? But if not, this may be helpful http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/MySQL_Wildcard_Filtering_using_LIKE

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server provides Full Text Search feature. You may try for this instead of your like clause.

Answer (score 0):

ATaylor pretty much spells it out for you. To exclude the specific common keywords, I would recommend using an "EXCEPT SELECT WHERE LIKE" statement at the end of your statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(field) AS var1, COUNT(field) AS var2 FROM table GROUP BY field HAVING var2 > 1;
```

This would show up any field that exist twice or more in your current database

Answer (score 0):

Full Text Search, you can have choice on you relevancy score. write a query to get the most relevant results.

```
SELECT MATCH('content') AGAINST ('keyword1 
keyword2') as relevancy_score FROM topic WHERE MATCH
('Content') AGAINST('+keyword1 +keyword2' IN 
BOOLEAN MODE) HAVING relevancy_score > 0.2 ORDER 
BY relevancy_score DESC.
```

you may refer to this link.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html